# Using $GET with HTML <li>

Tags: php, html, get

basically I have a 'tab' system made out of `<li>` and `<a>`'s with bootstrap. The code is as following

```
<ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
   <li name="tab" class="active"><a href="#unchecked"data-toggle="tab">Unchecked</a></li>
   <li name="tab" ><a href="#leave" data-toggle="tab">Leave as is</a></li>
   <li name="tab" ><a href="#add" data-toggle="tab">Add new</a></li>
   <li name="tab" ><a href="#up" data-toggle="tab">Uploaded</a></li>
   <li name="tab" ><a href="#app" data-toggle="tab">Approved</a></li>
</ul>
```

And what I want to achieve is each time the 'tab' is pushed, instead of switching to it, I want to refresh the whole page onto that new tab, probably using $GET, that way it doesnt have to load the content of each tab with just one tab active.

Comment: You question is unclear. How do you want the tab system to look, when you'll be using $_GET?

Answer (score 0):

If you use jquery library:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="tabs" class="nav nav-tabs" data-tabs="tabs">
   <li id="unchecked" name="tab" class="active"><a href="#unchecked"data-toggle="tab">Unchecked</a></li>
   <li id="leave" name="tab" ><a href="#leave" data-toggle="tab">Leave as is</a></li>
   <li id="add" name="tab" ><a href="#add" data-toggle="tab">Add new</a></li>
   <li id="up" name="tab" ><a href="#up" data-toggle="tab">Uploaded</a></li>
   <li id="app" name="tab" ><a href="#app" data-toggle="tab">Approved</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabresult"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#tabs li a").click(function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          // you can use .get method but i prefer post
          $.post('tabbody.php', {tab:$(this).parent()[0].id}, function(r) {
            // do what you want to change
            $("#tabresult").html(r);
          });
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And your tabbody.php script:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_REQUEST['tab']))
        switch ($_REQUEST['tab']) {
            case 'unchecked':
                echo '<div>Unchecked body</div>';
            break;
            case 'leave':
                echo '<div>leave body</div>';
            break;
            case 'add':
                echo '<div>add body</div>';
            break;
            case 'up':
                echo '<div>up body</div>';
            break;
            case 'app':
                echo '<div>app body</div>';
            break;
        }
?>
```